# Mapping enum properly in EF Core Code First Approach

Tags: c#, model, entity-framework-core

I have a library application and am trying to go with a code first approach which has a Book entity like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public Category? Category { get; set; }
}

public enum Category : byte
{
    [Description("LA_Category_Thriller")]
    Thriller,
    [Description("LA_Category_Adventure")]
    Adventure,
    [Description("LA_Category_Comic")]
    Comic,
    [Description("LA_Category_Mistery")]
    Mistery
}
```

Now I am coding a BookConfiguration class and I am not sure if I am doing stuff right; I am not sure what is the best solution, to convert to string, or to also enter it in DB like SQL-enum (not sure if even possible in EF Core):

```
public class BookConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Book> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Book), "lib");

        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
        builder.Property(b => b.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(b => b.Category)
            .HasMaxLength(32)
            .HasConversion<string>();

    }
}
```

As far as I got stuff this is goint to convert it to string upon updating an entry, but will this make stuff harder later when I retrieve values from db?

Comment: This is clearly C++, not C

Comment: @SGeorgiades looks like C# to me

Comment: It is c#, my bad